# Create SQLite Transaction using Alloy Models

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I tried create a transaction with the following code:

```
var db=Ti.Database.open('_alloy_');
db.execute('BEGIN;')
 //inserts
db.execute('COMMIT;');
```

But i have an exception:

```
SQLiteLog: (5) database is locked
[ERROR] :  SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/*/databases/_alloy_'.
```

Comment: I guess the database is still in use then, but that'll be hard to say without the context. Could you provide some more?

Comment: Current controller have a tableview with a AlloyCollection. And i implemented {AlloyModel}Dao in library to handle inserts

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't much I can do. If you'd have a full project then I could test if it's an environment issue or if I have the same problem.